# Unique validation for mobile number field

Tags: laravel

I am inserting a mobile number in the database and I want to create unique validation as an email field. It can not run for my controller. Need changes

**Controller:**

```
 $this->validate($req,
    [
        'client_name' =>'required',
        'email'=>'required|unique:table_client_registration',
        'mobileno'=>'numeric|unique:table_client_registration',
        'password'=>'required',
        'cpassword'=>'required|same:password'
    ],
    $messages);
```

**Blade:**

```
<div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col">
        <input type="text" name="mobile" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Mobile No">
        @if ($errors->has('mobileno')) <p style="color:red;">*{{ $errors->first('mobileno') }}</p> @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your field name is `mobile` and you are trying to validate a `mobileno`..

So either change it in your view to this:

```
<input type="text" name="mobileno" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Mobile No">
```

or in your validation

```
$this->validate($req,
    [
        'client_name' =>'required',
        'email'=>'required|unique:table_client_registration',
        'mobile'=>'numeric|unique:table_client_registration',
        'password'=>'required',
        'cpassword'=>'required|same:password'
    ],
    $messages);
```